# Concat python values based on similar keys in python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dictionary:

```
dct = { (1/1 , 2/1, 'AAPL') : pd.DataFrame({'aapl' : [1,2,3]}),
    (1/1, 2/1 , 'XOM') : pd.DataFrame({'xom' : [4,5,6]}) }
```

and what I would like to do is concat the dataframes based on the first 2 values of the key (for eg. if 1/1 and 2/1 are a match among keys, then concat those frames).

Results should look like:

```
dct = { (1/1 , 2/1) : pd.DataFrame({'aapl' : [1,2,3], 'xom' : [4,5,6] })
```

Comment: check [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: Does your input dictionary always have 2 items?

Comment: @jpp always 3 in the tuple, and one frame as value

Comment: @Sphinx ya i know of concat just unsure how to structure it in this dict

Comment: @thomas.mac, my question was does your input dictionary always have 2 items, i.e. 2 pairs of (a, b, c): pd.DataFrame?

Comment: @jpp oh sorry, no thats variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to collect a list of dataframes for each combination of keys, then concatenate once for each set.

I would *not* concatenate as I iterate the dictionary, as this will be expensive and unnecessary. In other words, concatenating 20 times for one tuple key is more expensive than concatenating a list of 20 dataframes once.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

dct = { ('1/1', '2/1', 'AAPL') : pd.DataFrame({'aapl' : [1,2,3]}),
        ('1/1', '2/1', 'XOM') : pd.DataFrame({'xom' : [4,5,6]}) }

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in dct.items():
    d[(k[0], k[1])].append(v)

res = {k: pd.concat(v, axis=1) for k, v in d.items()}

# {('1/1', '2/1'):    aapl  xom
#                  0     1    4
#                  1     2    5
#                  2     3    6}
```

Answer (score 4):

`defaultdict` would be one way to do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

# initialize defaultdict with an empty data frame as default value
result = defaultdict(pd.DataFrame)
​
for k, v in dct.items():
    result[k[:2]] = pd.concat([result[k[:2]], v], axis=1)

result
#defaultdict(pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, {('1/1', '2/1'):    aapl  xom
#             0     1    4
#             1     2    5
#             2     3    6})
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What's the issue with col names?

Comment: What python and pandas version are you using? This works in python 3.6, pandas 0.21.1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat` then iterate through a `groupby` with a dictionary comprehension.

```
d = pd.concat(dct, axis=1)
d.columns = d.columns.droplevel(2)

{k: v.xs(k, 1) for k, v in d.groupby(axis=1, level=[0, 1])}

{('1/1', '2/1'):    aapl  xom
 0     1    4
 1     2    5
 2     3    6}
```

Comment: That what I am going to do exactly same ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

loop the items of the dict, then concat dataframe if key[:2] is same.

The codes will be like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]], columns=['letter', 'number'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 3], ['b', 4]], columns=['letter', 'number'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 6], ['b', 7]], columns=['letter', 'number'])

dct = { ('1/1' , '2/1', 'AAPL') : df1,
        ('1/1', '2/1' , 'XOM') : df2,
        ('1/2', '2/1' , 'XOM') : df3,}

result = {}
for key, value in dct.items():
    if key[:2] in result:
        result[key[:2]] = pd.concat([result[key[:2]], value])
    else:
        result[key[:2]] = value
for key, value in result.items():
    print (key)
    print (value)
    print ('------------')
```

**Output:**

```
('1/1', '2/1')
  letter  number
0      a       1
1      b       2
0      a       3
1      b       4
------------
('1/2', '2/1')
  letter  number
0      a       6
1      b       7
------------
[Finished in 0.977s]
```